# Unit testing a library with AsUnit in Flex Builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flexbuilder, asunit

I've been trying to setup a working method for unit testing flex libraries using Flex Builder.

I have tried setting up a standard flex lib project and using Ant to compile and run the units tests. But this means that when something does go wrong and I want to use the flex builder debugger I cannot do so.

So my next plan is to setup the library as a normal as3/flax/air app as I can use the concept of a main class to run the unit tests. I can then compile the actual library code using Ant.

I could also setup a separate companion project who's sole task is to run units tests on the lib. But this is a little awkward as each library now requires two projects to manage.

This all seems a little messy to me.
How do other people develop flex libraries and use unit tests to test/develop/debug the code?

Answer (score 0):

What version do you use? Unit testing with FlexBuilder ist not very nice (understatement!).

If you have the opportunity, try FlashBuilder, it works much nicer and the new FlexUnit4 tests do integrate much better with CI than the old ones.

Comment: Will do I have downloaded the beta. To be honest i might jump over to FlexUnit as the documentation for AsUnit is pretty sparse.